# Installing Hebrew for LyX on OS X Yosemite

Tags: lyx, hebrew

I'm trying to install this as shown in the [this](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1dC3vK-iFCz_fwCsB9fhYuIF607fw4W9Vu0PdBDhLM0E/edit) link. But, I'm getting the following error message:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

I guess I haven't specifyied the folder, ok, or something similar, does someone have an idea?

Comment: What step have you reached and have you done everything until there?

Comment: Did you try to reconfigure LyX after the installation?

Comment: I download and installed the miketex, lyx. I download "culmus-latex-0.7-r1" and tried  to instal it through the terminal, but haven't success yet. I wrote on the terminal "sudo make TEXMFDIR=/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/
" and then I got the error message "make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop." , I'm guessing i had to write something before, someone has an idea??

Answer (score 1):

Since Macs use unicode fonts, I'd simply use them and process the files using XeTeX, rather than pdflatex. That way you can enter your Hebrew using the natural (and